# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 ошибка из за виртуального метода

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование

при компиляции получаю такю ошибку:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Ability::fight()", referenced from:
      _main in main-0e82f2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

после долгих попыток методом тыка понять где ошибка и почему она вылазит, пришел к тому что компилятор ругается из-за виртуального метода fight(), если сделать его обычным методом то все работает, но мне надо его переопределять в наследнике, может проблема с конструктором Ability из-за того что не заполняется vtable. короче я без понятия, могу только угадывать. помогите разобраться.

Army.hpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef ARMY_HPP
#define ARMY_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include "State.hpp"
#include "Ability.hpp"

class Ability;

class State;

class Army {
protected:
    std::string name;
    State* state;
    Ability* ability;
public:
    Army();
    ~Army();

    virtual Ability getAbility() = 0;
};

class Unit : virtual public Army {
protected:
    std::string name;
    State* state;
    Ability* ability;
public:
    Unit();
    Unit(std::string name, State* state, Ability* ability);
    ~Unit();
    Ability getAbility();
};
class Warewolf : public Unit {
public:
    Warewolf();
    ~Warewolf();
};
#endif /* Army_hpp */
```

**Army.cpp**

```
#include "Army.hpp"

Army::Army() {}
Army::~Army() {}

Unit::Unit() {}
Unit::Unit(std::string name, State* state, Ability* ability)  : name(name), state(state), ability(ability) {}
Unit::~Unit() {}
Ability Unit::getAbility() {
    return *ability;
}

Warewolf::Warewolf() : Unit("Warewolf", new WareWolfState(), new WarewolfAbility()) {}
Warewolf::~Warewolf() {}
```

**Ability.hpp**

```
#ifndef Ability_hpp
#define Ability_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "Army.hpp"

class Army;

class Ability {
protected:
    Army* unit;
public:
    Ability();
    Ability(Army *unit);
    ~Ability();
    virtual void fight() = 0;
};
class WarewolfAbility : public Ability {
public:
    WarewolfAbility();
    ~WarewolfAbility();
    void fight();
};
#endif /* Ability_hpp */
```

**Ability.cpp**

```
#include "Ability.hpp"

Ability::Ability() {}
Ability::Ability(Army *unit) : unit(unit) {}
Ability::~Ability() {}

WarewolfAbility::WarewolfAbility() : Ability(*this) {}
WarewolfAbility::~WarewolfAbility() {}

void WarewolfAbility::fight() {
    std::cout << "WAREWOLF FIGHT" << std::endl;
}
```

**State.hpp**

```
#ifndef STATE_HPP
#define STATE_HPP

#include <stdio.h>

class State {
protected:
    float hp;
    int damage;
public:
    State();
    State(float a, int b);
    ~State();
};
class WarewolfState : public State {
public:
    WarewolfState();
    ~WarewolfState();
};

#endif
```

**State.cpp**

```
#include "State.hpp"
#include <iostream>

State::State() {}
State::State(float a, int b) : hp(a), damage(b) {}
State::~State() {}

WarewolfState::WarewolfState() : State(200.0,65) {}
WarewolfState::~WarewolfState() {}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Army.hpp"

int main() {
    Army* wolf = new Warewolf();

    wolf->getAbility().fight();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: сейчас сделаю, пару мин @Abyx

Comment: @Abyx убрал сколько смог

Comment: а вы пробовали удалить из кода полностью метод fight() ? это бы сузило область проблемы.

Comment: @perfect пробывал. Если в классе Ability делать fight() не виртуальным то все работает

Comment: похоже что то с линковщиком попробуйте определение и реализацию разместить в одном файле

Comment: кстати поробуйте собирать с ключом -v наверняка получите больше информации как вам советует линкер

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вместо `Ability getAbility()` должно быть `Ability& getAbility()`.

Если возвращать не ссылку, а значение - то происходит *срезка*, создается новый объект Ability, у которого нет тела функции `fight()`.
По идее компилятор должен выдавать ошибку "нельзя создать объект абстрактного типа", но он почему-то этого не делает, и вместо этого возникает ошибка линковки.

Comment: спасибо, работает

Comment: А должен ли? Он ведь не создаёт этот объект нигде явно.

Comment: По поводу срезки вопросов не имею, я про ту часть, что компилятор должен выдавать ошибку. На мой взгляд, тут не по чему выдавать ошибку, т.к. нет прямого создания

Comment: @Abyx, как это нет никакой разницы? Мы имеем случай конструктора копирования, поэтому никакой ошибки быть и не должно, по крайней мере я не вижу причин, чтобы эта ошибка была обязательно.

Comment: @Abyx, это я что-то попутал. Увидев ошибку линкера, а не компилятора я, почему-то, решил, что создать копированием абстрактный класс можно. Кстати, все 3 компилятора выдают ошибку на подобный код, странно, что у автора тогда нет ошибки. Видимо clang какой-то старый

Answer (score 0):

похоже проблема в том что вы вызываете виртуальный метод **getAbility** из класса **Army** у которого нет тела (реализации).